# How to make autocomplete input field out of existing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've included javascript and HTML code, not full, but hopefully enough to give you idea. At the moment It works this way:
- If I click on input (id=zipcode), it shows prompt box in which you enter ZIP code.

I would like to know, if i can get rid of this prompt box and just do it this way:
- If I click on input  (id=zipcode), it just shows a "bubble" with text above the input field "enter a zip code and the city/state will be pre-filled" ... basicaly I would like to make autocompleter on the ZIP input field...

Javascript code:

```
function prefillLocale(zip)
{
    var doc, City, State, ZipCode;

    ZipCode = document.getElementById("ZipCode");
    City = document.getElementById("City");
    State = document.getElementById("State");
    doc = ajax(doc);

    // Load the result from the response page
    // ** As far a I know firefox will only load a document on the SAME domain!!    
    if (doc)
    {
        var cmd = "../ajaxLocales.php?type=zip2cs&z=" + zip;

        doc.open("GET", cmd, false);
        doc.send(null);

        var arraylist=doc.responseText.split("|");

        City.value = arraylist[0];
        State.value = arraylist[1];
            ZipCode.value = zip;
        }
        return true;
    }

        var bDoneOnce = new Array();

        function getZip1(ID

)
    {
        if(bDoneOnce[ID] != undefined)  return;
        bDoneOnce[ID] = 1;

        var zip=prompt("Enter a zip code and the city/state will be pre-filled.","");
        if (zip!=null && zip!="")
        {
            prefillLocale1(zip,ID);
        }
        document.getElementById("City"+ID).focus();
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div style="margin-left: 182px;">
<input type="text" onfocus="getZip1(50);" class="ac_input" value="Texas" id="State50" size="15" name="State">
<input type="text" onfocus="getZip1(50);" class="ac_input" value="75038" id="ZipCode50" size="5" maxlength="5" name="ZipCode">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UPDATE

```
 - Was going to update this with personally written code, but then a co-worker 
   filled me on the following link
```

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/05/29/using-jquery-autocomplete-to-populate-another-autocomplete-asp-net-coldfusion-and-php-examples/

> And another great example (with ASP and Coldusion examples!!!)

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/05/29/using-jquery-autocomplete-to-populate-another-autocomplete-asp-net-coldfusion-and-php-examples/

```
 - Looks like it would probably be better you start there as my explanation 
   would probably go too deep into the depth of getting everything setup.  
 - Give that sight a try, and if you have anymore questions, 
   feel free to hit me back up, though I'm quite sure if you go through his 
   walk-through, with a little more jQuery understanding, you'll be able to do 
   exactly what you want to do when you're done.
```

> Don't forget to get jQueryUI so you can make use of [this awesome](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) jQuery add-in

I am unclear as to your full intentions, especially since your code makes very little sense.  However, I was able to interpret some parts and point out some things "general practices" for use with jQuery.  Below is the best interpretation of your code with jQuery specific changes, the biggest one being, you no longer need `ocument.getElementById` as jQuery has replaced this with a simple `$(insertElementIdOrClassNameOrCssSelectorHere)`.  You will find jQuery makes almost everything in javascript...Easier!

Your previous code: (*gimmie feed back and I will attempt to help you fully fix the problem*)

```
function prefillLocale(zip) {
    var doc = ajax(doc),    // ?!?
        City = $("City"),
        State = $("State"),
        ZipCode = $("ZipCode");

    // Load the result from the response page
    // ** As far a I know firefox will only load a document on the SAME domain!!
    if (doc) {
        var cmd = "../ajaxLocales.php?type=zip2cs&z=" + zip;

        doc.open("GET", cmd, false);
        doc.send(null);

        var arraylist=doc.responseText.split("|");

        City.value = arraylist[0];
        State.value = arraylist[1];
        ZipCode.value = zip;
        return true;
    }

    var bDoneOnce = new Array();

    function getZip1(ID) {
        if(bDoneOnce[ID] != undefined)  return;
        bDoneOnce[ID] = 1;

        var zip=prompt("Enter a zip code and the city/state will be pre-filled.","");
        if (zip!=null && zip!="") {
            prefillLocale1(zip,ID);
        }
        $("#City"+ID).focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: my intention is to remove prompt aka alert box, i want to type in zip, but while im typing into the input box, i get suggestions in drop-down... and when i select, for example this suggestion (Texas | Houston), it will pre-fill other input fields (state and city) on clicking, selecting that suggestion.

Comment: Just so you know, extremely busy at work today and this will take a good minute of explanation.  I will try to get you a jsFiddle of an example of what I think you are looking to do by tonight.

Comment: bleh, family life. Anyway, just checking in, still havn't been able to make that fiddle, I'll try to get to it first thing in morning, sure i wont have much else to do when i get to the office in morning anyway, lol.  FYI, autocomplete for this should be relativly easy and what you'll probably want to add is [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) as it includes an autocompelte.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add a focus event to the input, then in that event display your prompt text.  With jQuery version 1.7.1 you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('focusin','#ZipCode50', function(){
      // do your display here
    });
    $(document).on('blur focusout','#ZipCode50', function(){
      // remove your display here
    });
})
```